# Calling functions by using indexers created by typeof keyof

Tags: typescript, typeof, keyof

I'm trying to understand in what way can I call static functions dynamically, accessing the functions' class using an indexer.

Consider this simple example:

`Comparer.ts` defines static functions:

```js
class Comparer {
    static strings(a: string, b: string) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }

    static numbers(a: number, b: number) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

`Comparers.ts` defines the functions' "types", so to say:

```js
enum Comparers {
    strings,
    numbers,
}
```

And in `index.ts`, I want to call the functions using the enum:

```js
type ComparerKey = keyof typeof Comparer;

const result = Comparer[Comparers.strings as ComparerKey]("a", "b");
console.log(result);
```

However, I get the error:

> This expression is not callable.
> Not all constituents of type 'Comparer | ((a: string, b: string) => number) | ((a: number, b: number) => 1 | -1 | 0)' are callable.
> Type 'Comparer' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
>
> Conversion of type 'Comparers' to type '"prototype" | "strings" | "numbers"' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)

IIUC, the reason it doesn't work is because the `keyof typeof` operator decomposes the type into `prototype` (as well as `strings` and `numbers`), which is not callable.

- Note that there's another way to approach this - and it's without using `keyof typeof`, but instead assign the enums with strings:

  ```js
  enum Comparers {
       strings = "strings",
       numbers = "numbers",
  }
  const result = Comparer[Comparers.strings]("a", "b"); // no error now
  console.log(result);
  ```

Question: is it even possible to use the `keyof typeof` operator in this case to make the call work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the enum with no explicit values will have unsigned integers as values:

```
enum Comparers {
    strings, // will be 0
    numbers, // will be 1
}
```

Thus, trying to get the method of `Comparer` by using this enum doesn't make any sense, since there is nothing in the class that is `0` or `1`

The only valid option is to give the explicit values to the enum:

```
enum Comparers {
  strings = 'strings',
  numbers = 'numbers',
}
```

If you want to have the type for the keys anyway you can manually remove the `prototype` from the union using built-in [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type:

```
type Keys = Exclude<keyof typeof Comparer, 'prototype'>
```